# Checking for variable to be non-empty in bash

Tags: bash

I want to run a remote command over ssh. So, the one line command is

```
ssh root@10.1.1.101 'VMID=`./run_prog` && if [ -n $VMID ]; then echo "id=$VMID"; vim-cmd vmsvc/power.off $VMID; else echo "$VMID empty"; fi'
```

Problem is that if `VMID` is empty or non-empty, I see the output of `vim-cmd`.

```
id=
Usage: power.off vmid
```

or

```
34
Powering off VM:
```

How can I be sure that `vim-cmd` is executed for non-empty `VMID` values?

Comment: Do you really need `VMID empty` to be output? Would the lack of any other output be sufficient to indicate that it was empty?

Comment: Also, does `run_prog` have a non-zero exit status if it fails to produce any output? You could test that instead of explicitly checking the contents of the variable. `VMID=$(./run_prog) && vim-cmd vmsvc/power.off "$VIMD"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you do not quote the variable inside the `if` condition. You have to do it this way:

```
if [ -n "$VMID" ]
```

You might wonder why if you don't quote you face problems. Well the answer is in [man test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test):

> -n STRING
>     the length of STRING is nonzero 
> STRING
>     equivalent to -n STRING

So when `VMID` is empty, the `if` condition results like this:

```
if [ -n ]
```

and `test` will assume that you want to check if `-n` is an empty string. It won't undestand that you have used `-n` as an option. So, `-n` is not empty and the test passes.

If you use quotation, `test` will understand what you want.

If I can add a suggestion, don't use backquotes for command substitution. Use `$(./run_prog)` instead. Check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) if you want more information about it.